# Subclassed NSView to notify ViewController of action

Tags: swift, macos, drag-and-drop, nsview

I have subclassed NSView to receive a dropped folder in order to get its URL.
I've been getting the URL to my ViewController class by accessing a property set in my custom NSView class.

```
import Cocoa

class DropView: NSView {
    var droppedURL : URL!

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        // Drawing code here.
    }
    public required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super .init(coder: coder)
        registerForDraggedTypes([NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.fileURL])
    }
    
    public override func draggingEntered(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {
        return NSDragOperation.copy
    }
    public override func draggingUpdated(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {
        NSDragOperation.copy
    }
    public override func performDragOperation(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
        let pboard = sender.draggingPasteboard
        let urlString = pboard.string(forType: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.fileURL)
        let folderURL = URL(string: urlString!)
        print(folderURL)
        droppedURL = folderURL
        return true
    }
    
}
```

How can I let my ViewController know when a folder has been dropped onto my NSView and that a URL has been successfully captured? Is there a way other than posting a notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you'd use [delegates](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/) or [closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html) for this. I prefer closures because they're so clean, but it's up to you.

First, define your closure in `DropView`:

```
class DropView: NSView {
    var droppedURL : URL!
    var droppedSuccessfully: ((URL) -> Void)? /// here!
```

Then, call it just like how you'd call a function. Make sure to pass in your `folderURL` too.

```
public override func performDragOperation(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
    let pboard = sender.draggingPasteboard
    let urlString = pboard.string(forType: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.fileURL)
    let folderURL = URL(string: urlString!)
    print(folderURL)
    droppedURL = folderURL
    droppedSuccessfully?(folderURL) /// here!
    return true
}
```

Finally, assign the closure back in your `ViewController`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ...
                                         /// prevent retain cycle
    yourDropView.droppedSuccessfully = { [weak self] url in
        print("URL received: \(url)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! In addition to solving my immediate need it helped to fill in my understanding of closures.

Comment: Do I need to somehow initialize droppedSuccessfully in my init function? I suppose I'm starting to wrap my head around closures in general (defining and calling) but how would I initialize a closure?

Comment: @psb there's no need to initialize `droppedSuccessfully` in your init function, because it's an optional `((URL) -> Void)?`. Note the `?` at the end - by default, it will automatically be `nil`. However, if you want to initialize it, sure. Your init would look something like `init(droppedURL: URL, droppedSuccessfully: @escaping ((URL) -> Void)) { self.droppedURL = droppedURL;  self.droppedSuccessfully = droppedSuccessfully }`

Comment: I just figured that out after investigating a bit more. Again, thanks so much. I'm finding closures to be not very intuitive but I'm slowly wrapping my head around them. You're answers have really helped me with this.